# Extract data from html using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Im trying to extract the data which is under EXPERIENCE tag. Im using beautifulsoup to extract the data. Below is my html:

```
<div><span>EXPERIENCE

<br/></span></div><div><span>

<br/></span></div><div><span>

<br/></span></div><div><span></span><span> </span><span>I worked in XYZ company from 2016 - 2018

<br/></span></div><div><span> I worked on JAVA platform

<br/></span></div><div><span>From then i worked in ABC company

</br>2018- Till date

</br></span></div><div><span>I got handson on Python Language

</br></span></div><div><span>PROJECTS

</br></span></div><div><span>Developed and optimized many application, etc...
```

My work till now:

```
with open('E:/cvparser/test.html','rb') as h:

    dh = h.read().splitlines()

    out = str(dh)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(out,'html.parser')

    for tag in soup.select('div:has(span:contains("EXPERIENCE"))'):

        final = (tag.get_text(strip = True, separator = '\n'))

    print(final)
```

Expected Output:

```
I worked in XYZ company from 2016 - 2018

I worked on JAVA platform

From then i worked in ABC company

2018- Till date

I got handson on Python Language
```

For my code its returning null. Can someone help me out here?

Comment: just to clarify, EXPERIENCE is not a tag. The tag you're interested in is the `<span>` tag. So you are looking for the data under the `span` tag that contains the text/content `EXPERIENCE`

Comment: This is almost cetainly a duplicate. I have seen this same question three times recently in only slightly different forms.

Answer (score 2):

What I understood is you want to have text in `span` between **EXPERIENCE** and **PROJECTS**

Here is what you need:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

html = """<div><span>EXPERIENCE

<br/></span></div><div><span>

<br/></span></div><div><span>

<br/></span></div><div><span></span><span> </span><span>I worked in XYZ company from 2016 - 2018

<br/></span></div><div><span> I worked on JAVA platform

<br/></span></div><div><span>From then i worked in ABC company

</br>2018- Till date

</br></span></div><div><span>I got handson on Python Language

</br></span></div><div><span>PROJECTS
</br></span></div><div><span>Developed and optimized many application, etc...</span></div>"""

page = soup(html, "html.parser")

save = False
final = ''
for div in page.find_all('div'):
    text = div.get_text()

    if text and text.strip().replace('\n','') == 'PROJECTS':
        save = False

    if save and text and text.strip().replace('\n', ''):
        # last if is to avoid new line in final result
        final = '{0}\n{1}'.format(final,text.replace('\n',''))
    else:
        if text and 'EXPERIENCE' in text:
            save = True

print(final)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
 I worked in XYZ company from 2016 - 2018
 I worked on JAVA platform
From then i worked in ABC company
I got handson on Python Language
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your html example, but try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
result2 = requests.get("") # your url here
src2 = result2.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src2, 'lxml')


for item in soup.find_all('div', {'span': 'Experience'}): 
    print(item.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to match all relevant sub contents to their appropriate header:

```
import itertools, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = lambda x:[i for b in x.contents for i in ([b] if b.name is None else d(b))]
data = list(filter(None, map(lambda x:re.sub('\n+|^\s+', '', x), d(soup(html, 'html.parser')))))
new_d = [list(b) for _, b in groupby(data, key=lambda x:x.isupper())]
result = {new_d[i][0]:new_d[i+1] for i in range(0, len(new_d), 2)}
```

Output:

```
{'EXPERIENCE': ['\uf0b7', 'I worked in XYZ company from 2016 - 2018', 'I worked on JAVA platform', 'From then i worked in ABC company', 'I got handson on Python Language'], 'PROJECTS': ['Developed and optimized many application, etc...']}
```

To get your desired output:

```
print('\n'.join(result['EXPERIENCE']))
```

Output:

```

I worked in XYZ company from 2016 - 2018
I worked on JAVA platform
From then i worked in ABC company
2018- Till date
I got handson on Python Language
```

Comment: It gave me list index out of range.@Ajax1234